# Since I installed 14.04 I'm missing app indicator for sonata

Tags: unity, indicator, mpd

I don't know if there ever was an app-indicator for Sonata. I had Linux Mint before. Does anyone knows how to restore / install it on Ubuntu 14 (unity)?

As an alternative, is there a good (slim, sonata-like) MPD client that fully-integrates with unity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a sonata-like client for MPD covering all wishes: [cantata](https://github.com/cdrummond/cantata) :-)

And it has a really nice integration with unity including Play/Pause and currently playing on the sound indicator-menu.